# Are there tools/libraries that can generate a full java software server stack from a set of POJOs?

Tags: library, java, software-development, web-server

I'd like to generate a full software stack from a set of POJOs. The generated layers would be:

1. CRUD DB operations.
2. Search data.
3. User management (Integration with FB/Google/OpenId/etc.)
4. Permissions using annotations (authorization).
5. (restful) APIs.
6. Plugins to handle changes in data.
7. Libraries for changing the data.
8. Connectivity between the different POJOs.

For example, consider a candy store inventory.
I'd like to have a simple pojo layer and have everything generated for it.
class Candy {
  int name;
  int weight;
  int color;
  int num;
}

Here are examples of what I'd like to be able to do using the generated layers respectively to the generated layers above:

1. Add a new candy to the DB (Using jdbc prepared statements).
2. Search a candy by name.
3. Know who searches the store.
4. Seller can add candies but not store visitors.
5. API to add new candies to the store.
6. Notify the factory if the number of one of the candies is lower than 50.
7. Adding a buy functionality that lowers the number of candies.
8. When add a new Pojo, like Ingredient, The tool will know to connect between the candy and the ingredients, so I can get the list of candies by searching for a specific ingredient (but not always return the ingredients).

**Anyone knows of such a tool/library?**

In other languages perhaps?

With the majority of the functionality but not all?

BTW, there can be more functionalities, like push notifications, and others.

Comment: I can imagine a tool that provides straight CRUD for each POJO (and thus for a set of POJOs) or other predefined functionalities.   But  you'd have to specify the set somehow; surely it is hard to believe that one exists that does exactly what you've listed ("know who searches the store"? That implies a "who" object with login and tracking).  I think you expect it to support functionalities you have not listed. How do you expect the tool to handle those?

Comment: @IraBaxter, 1. Regarding defining the set of POJOs, it can just be an input jar to the tool. 2. Regarding the "who", I indeed expect a mechanism for signing in (with FB?), and using auth tokens to identify the user.
3. Regarding permissions, and who's allowed to do what, I still don't know how it can be plugged into the POJO's. My initial thought is using some annotations. 4. Basically, I'm still not trying to develop such a tool, but rather find one.